# Is there a way to integrate eventbridge with xray without using a lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions, aws-event-bridge, aws-xray, distributed-tracing

Is there a way to integrate eventbridge with X-ray without using a lambda? In step functions you can use the direct API drag and drop methods of adding services. Is it possible to enable tracing for an event sent to eventbridge from step functions without involving a lambda as shown in [this tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-aws-x-ray-tracing-with-amazon-eventbridge/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for raising question to X-Ray.
The quick answer is no.
There are 2 types of service and X-Ray integration: Active and only Passthrough.

1. The Active integration means the AWS managed service is able to emit Segment representing itself if user `enable` tracing for the AWS resource. If not enable tracing, it is passthrough mode by default.
2. The Passthough only integrated AWS managed service means it just passthrough trace context from incoming request to downstream.

AWS EventBridge is passthough only integrated, so, the node in xray console is inferred by its upstream, it could be a Lambda or whatever as long as it emits a Subsegment representing a call to EventBridge.

Comment: Thank you. 
Let us say I have a step function that has enabled tracing. In the step function there is an EventBridge integration that receives a trace id from the step function and also emits an event. Will the service map in the X-ray console show downstream services triggered by EventBridge? I want to see downstream services triggered by EventBridge in the X-ray service map. What should I do to achieve this? This is the kind of flow I would like to see `HTTP API` => `step function` => `EventBridge` => `Step function`  => `EventBridge` => `step function` => `EventBridge` => `IotCore`.

Comment: Hey Lei Wang, I have [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77219604/how-to-intergrate-aws-x-ray-with-this-format-stepfunction-eventbridge-down) on X-Ray here. Thank you.