# How to integrate AWS X-ray with this format StepFunction => EventBridge => Downstream services

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-event-bridge, aws-xray, distributed-tracing, observability

How to include EventBridge Triggered Downstream Services in X-ray Service Map?

I have a step function with tracing enabled, and within this step function, there's an EventBridge integration that both receives a trace ID from the step function and emits an event. My goal is to visualize the downstream services triggered by EventBridge in the X-ray service map.

The desired flow I'd like to see in the X-ray service map is as follows:

`HTTP API` (this part is optional) => `Step function` => `EventBridge` => `Step function` => `EventBridge` => `Step function` => `EventBridge` => `IoT Core`

The HTTP API part is optional as I think it is not possible to integrate `HTTP API` with AWS X-ray, but I am aware it is possible to do so with `REST API`.

However, when I check the X-ray service map, it doesn't seem to show the downstream services triggered by EventBridge. What steps should I take to achieve this visualization in the X-ray service map?

Comment: Does your downstream stepfunction also has tracing enabled? Does the same trace id propagate from upstream stepfunction to downstream via the EventBridge event?

Comment: Hey, I did that and that was the solution. I am also calling EventBridge from a lambda with tracing enabled.